# View model not resolved when using an interface with Xamarin Forms and Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, caliburn.micro

I am attempting to register an interface for a viewmodel, so that I can inject the interface into another view model. I have something similar to the following code in the app constructor in a shared .net standard class library in a Xamarin Forms app using Caliburn Micro.

```
public App(SimpleContainer container)
{     
    this._container = container;
    _container.Singleton<ISetupViewModel, SetupViewModel>();
    InitializeComponent();
    DisplayRootView<SetupView>();
 }
```

Using this will display the correct view is displayed, however the SetupViewModel doesn’t get created. But when I change the registration to not use the interface as below, then the SetupViewModel is created and resolved.

```
_container.Singleton<SetupViewModel>();
```

Is there any reason that I can't register a view model with an interface?

Comment: Why do you expect your program to look for `ISetupViewModel` when creating a `SetupView`?

Comment: The view model locator inside Caliburn Micro resolves the correct view model when using DisplayRootView in the first scenario. I don't expect any different behavior to change when registering the view model with an interface in the IoC container.

Comment: Why not? There are rules on how CM resolves view/viewmodel names. If you register the service to be `ISetupViewModel`, then I would suspect the need for a resolution rule that results in `ISetupViewModel` instead of `SetupViewModel`. Do you have any documentation hints that support _your_ expectations?